# Spring advice on MVC method with argument missing

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-aop

*****Edit*****

I think there is some confusion, I am not using both of the below methods in my controller.  I am just using "doMethod(HttpServletRequest request)".  My advice then applies and works accordingly.  My problem is that "doMethod(HttpServletRequest request)" does not need the HttpServletRequest argument, only the advice which is applied to it uses it.  So I was wondering if I can change my method from "doMethod(HttpServletRequest request)" to "doMethod()" but still be able to intercept the HttpServletRequest with the advice applied to it (Because I know spring has access to it somewhere)

In spring MVC you can have a method like so:

```
@RequestMapping
public void doMethod() {
    //some logic here
}
```

And if I need some other argument I can change it to this:

```
@RequestMapping
public void doMethod(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    //some logic with request
}
```

And spring will delegate to the same method either way, but fill in the argument for me if I add it through some wizardry (which I don't understand)

My question is when doing aop like so:

```
@Before(value=(execution(* * com.domain.package.doMethod(..)), argNames=httpServletRequest)
public void advice(HttpServletRequest httpServetRequest) {
    //some before advice
}
```

This makes sense when applying to the second method definition, but how could I get this to  work with the first one when it doesn't contain the 'HttpServletRequest' argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can do what you want. Spring MVC injects argument taking them from HTTP request (attributes, URL etc). They also support a list of "built-in" arguments that if mentioned are always sent.

When your controller is called normally in HTTP request context the instance of `HttpRequest` will be always sent, so the first, no-arguments version of this method will be never called.

To make it called you should either map it to different URL or different HTTP method or different content type.